# rsync exlude list from database?

Tags: sqlite, rsync

I know I can exclude rsync files listed in a text file, but can I make rsync read a sqlite (or other) database as an exclude list?

Otherwise I guess I could dump the sqlite to a text file, but I would like to eliminate the extra step, since I have many files in many directories.

Answer (score 2):

The man page says:

> `--exclude-from=FILE`
>   This option is related to the `--exclude` option, but it specifies a FILE that contains exclude patterns (one per line). Blank lines in the file and lines starting with ";" or "#" are ignored. If FILE is `-`, the list will be read from standard input.

So just pipe the file names into rsync:

```sh
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT filename FROM t" | rsync --exclude-from=- ...
```